# Butterknife determine which button clicked from multiple onclick bind

Tags: android, butterknife

Currently, it's my first time using `butterknife` and I'm binding multiple buttons into a single method. How will I know which `button` has been clicked?

```
@OnClick({R.id.LoadAmount10,R.id.LoadAmount20,R.id.LoadAmount30,R.id.LoadAmount5 
                0,R.id.LoadAmount100,R.id.LoadAmount300,R.id.LoadAmount500})
    public void setLoadAmount(){

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Check using **`SWITCH CASE`** inside `@OnClick({......})` like following..

```
  @OnClick({R.id.LoadAmount10,R.id.LoadAmount20,R.id.LoadAmount30,R.id.LoadAmount50,R.id.LoadAmount100,R.id.LoadAmount300,R.id.LoadAmount500})
  public void setLoadAmount(View view){
      switch(view.getId()){
         case R.id.LoadAmount10:
             break;
         .....
         .....
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
    @OnClick({R.id.LoadAmount10, R.id.LoadAmount20})
public void onItemClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.LoadAmount10:
            // do something here
            break;
        case R.id.LoadAmount20:
            // do something here
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a group of buttons to have one task to do then I'll suggest you to go with checkbox or radio buttons.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. These buttons could be links, and then neither checkboxes nor radio buttons would be appropriate. We have to assume that askers are looking for a particular answer for a reason.

Comment: @heath3n Thank you for the correcting me. I have just started out.

Comment: No worries. It is sometimes good to offer alternative solutions (in case the asker seems to be falling into the [XY trap](http://xyproblem.info/)) but I would try to do that in either a comment or as additional information to an answer to their question or otherwise you may get downvoted for providing non-answers. That being said, welcome to Stack Overflow!